# Extensions not saved across devices in VSCode Portable Edition v1.74.3

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using version 1.74.3 of the VSCode Portable Edition, stored on a pendrive, and I am encountering an issue with extensions not being saved across devices. When I install an extension in the portable version, it does not persist if I move the file to another computer. I expect the installed extensions to be saved in the portable version and accessible on any device where I run the portable version from the pendrive. Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Operating System: Windows 10
VSCode Portable Edition Version: 1.74.3

I have tried installing extensions in the VSCode Portable Edition, but they do not persist when I move the file to another computer. I expected the installed extensions to be saved within the portable version and accessible on any device where I run the portable version from the pendrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like this issue raised on GitHub: ["Portable VS Code Extensions do not Transfer to Other Computers (#171569)"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171569)

[which is reported to be fixed in the insiders build for v1.75](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171569#issuecomment-1386425906)

While you're waiting for 1.75 to be officially released to the general public, you can switch to the insiders version.

Update: VS Code 1.75 was released on 2023 Jan 2nd at 11:50 AM PST. See the [releases on their GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases). The release notes can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75).

Comment: Thank you for your help. But It seems v1.75 is not released yet. Waiting to be fixed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SkMiraj updated answer. v1.75 was just released.